# IOS download image, tableViewCell and Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have an Array.
Inside my array have 8 object seriated:

```
 - text
 - text
 - link Url Image.
 - link Url Image.
 - text
 - link Url Image.
 - link Url Image.
 - text
```

I had downloaded all image and save to document folder.
And now, How can I get all image from document folder and show in tableViewCell seriated same myArray?

I used this code to get all image from document folder.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *myPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *directoryContents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:myPath error:nil];
NSMutableArray *subpredicates = [NSMutableArray array];
            [_arrMessageFree addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF ENDSWITH '.png'"]];
            [_ar addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF ENDSWITH '.jpg'"]];
NSPredicate *filter = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpredicates];

NSArray *onlyImages = [directoryContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

But, I cannot show both text and image seriated in myArray.

Comment: array onlyImages have imagename or nil?

Comment: onlyImages is not nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

//after cell initialization add following code

         for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) 
          {
                     [subview removeFromSuperview];
          }
          UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[onlyImages objectAtIndex:indextPath.row]];
          [cell.contentView addSubview:img];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have told, you are able to get the image names into `onlyImages` array after the following line:

```
NSArray *onlyImages = [directoryContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

So let's use it to fetch and create `UIImages`:

```
UIImage *temp = nil;
for (int i = 0; i < [onlyImages count]; i++) {
   temp = [UIImage imageNamed:[onlyImages objectAtIndex:i]]; // so now you have your image loaded into `temp` UIImage object
}
```

Hope this was helpful!

Cheers!

Comment: Ok, just do the following:<br/>
`NSLog(@"Image Names : %@",[onlyImages objectAtIndex:i]);`
And tell me what will be the output? or is `onlyImages` array is totally empty?